# The characteristic polynomial of A matrix A^k related to A

Tags: matrices

when I'm learning markov matrix

[markov pdf download here](http://www.numbertheory.org/courses/MP274/markov.pdf)

when proving THEOREM 4.12,
It said,
characteristic polynomial of a matrix A
$ch(A) =(x−c_1)^{a_1} ···(x−c_t)^{a_t} ⇒ ch(A^k) =(x−c_1^k)^{a_1} ···(x−c_t^k)^{a_t}$.
why is that? I can understand that if $c_1$ is eigenvalue of A, then $c_k$ is eigenvalue
of $A^k$,(and the eigenvector can be same), but why is the algebra multiplicity the same?

besides, the eigenvector of A and $A^k$ is same, but is it true for generalized eigenvector?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is a matrix in $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$ then it's trigonalizable over $\Bbb C$ i.e. there's an invertible matrix $P$ such that

$$A=PTP^{-1}$$
where

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}c_1&\times&\cdots&\cdots&\times\\ &\ddots&&&\vdots\\ &&\ddots&&\times\\&&&&c_{a_t} \end{pmatrix}$$
is a triangular matrix and $c_i$'s their eigenvalues.
Now we see that

$$A=PT^kP^{-1}$$
where
$$T^k=\begin{pmatrix}c_1^k&\times&\cdots&\cdots&\times\\ &\ddots&&&\vdots\\ &&\ddots&&\times\\&&&&c_{a_t}^k \end{pmatrix}$$
so the characteristic polynomial of $T^k$ is

$$\chi_{T^k}(x)=\det(xI_n-T^k)=\prod_{i=1}^t(x-c_i^k)^{a_i}$$